# Send data from view to controller in Asp.net Mvc4

Tags: html, image, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, postback

How can send html **img** atribute value from view to controller?

```
<div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                @if (Model == null)
                {
                    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image" />
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Sender.Logofile))
                    {
                    <img src="~/Content/img/Company/LogoFiles/@Model.Sender.Logofile" id="logoimg"/>
                    }
                }
            </div>
            <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
            <div>
                <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
                    <input type="file" id="LogoFileUp" name="LogoFileUp" size="19" style="opacity: 0;" data-form="uniform" required="required" /></span>
                <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
            </div>
```

I want to check that Has value got img **logoimg** or not? How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an hidden input whose value is your img's src.

Comment: If I don't use any Model property as image, How can I get img href in controller in other way?

Comment: Request.Form["hidden input name"]

Answer (score 2):

Add an  input(hidden) whose has got same value as your img's src 
.